# django one-to-one fields with User model with using serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

The User model and UserProfile model are connected with one-to-one field .I want to post data through serializer but the program gives error...

this is model code..

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    GENDERS = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('T', 'Transgender'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True)   
    contactno = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDERS,blank=True,    null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True)
    state = ChainedForeignKey(State,chained_field="country",    chained_model_field="country", null=True)
    city = ChainedForeignKey(City,chained_field="state",  chained_model_field="state", null=True)
    pin_code = models.IntegerField( null=True, blank=True, default = None)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'User Profile'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

this is serializer code...

```
class userProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ("dob","contactno","country","state","city",'user')





class userSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dob = userProfileSerializer()
    contactno = userProfileSerializer()
    country = countrySerializer()
    state = stateSerializer()
    city = citySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields =  ('username','email','password',"dob","contactno","country","state","city")


    def create(self, validated_data):
        dob_data = validated_data.pop('dob')
        contactno_data = validated_data.pop('contactno')
        country_data = validated_data.pop('country')
        state_data = validated_data.pop('state')
        city_data = validated_data.pop('city')


        user = User.objects.create(username=validated_data['username'],email=validated_data['email'],password=validated_data['password'])
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
                UserProfile.objects.create(user=user,dob=dob_data,contactno=contactno_data,country=country_data,state=state_data,city=city_data)
    return user
```

it will be very great if anyone help me....

Comment: Showing the error would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need special serializer for `UserProfile` if you just want to save `UserProfile` like that.

Here is a minimal example only using `dob` field, but the same rules apply to the other fields.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields =('username','email','password', 'dob')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        dob_data = validated_data.pop('dob')

        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data.get('username'),
            email=validated_data.get('email'),
            password=validated_data.get('password')
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data.get('password'))
        user.save()

        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, dob=dob_data)
        return user
```

Comment: when I use POST method it gives error...   {"user":["This field is required."]}

Comment: Are you copying my example verbatim? Because in my example `user` is being set when creating `UserProfile` instance, so it does not give that error. Please use my example as is and try to work from there.

Comment: sorry to disturb you ... but I am new in stackflow ...so tell me how to do that and I will do it

Comment: there is a "tick" under the upvote/downvote right next to my answer
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d6vqbp5xys8vffe/Screenshot%202017-02-16%2009.30.01.png?dl=0
just click that "tick" and that's it :)